# StackedBarChart in Javascript d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[This image is the descript of how I create the groups and then the rect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGBC3.png)I'm implementing a script based on the stackedbar charts in javascript, each bar is composed of a section representing one of the quantitative attributes, my problem is the following: I have to click on a section of the bar representing one of the attributes and this section will have to take the place than the one above, this must be done in each bar. Can someone help me. Thank you all

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code you are using it is difficult to give an answer that is useful. I can guess how you create the chart, but this risks time spent answering for me, and time spent applying the solution for you, on an answer that may not work for your situation. You'll likely have better luck in finding an answer if you include minimal code to replicate the barchart here along with anything you've tried so far. Also, do you want to swap the bar segment with the one above it, or just move it over the bar segment above it?

Comment: [How to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes sorry,tommorrow i will put the code for the creation of the stacked bar. Wherever yes i want to swap the bar segment with the one Above it, i dont know what type of function in d3.js i can use it, the single bar is composed from 5 quantitative attribuite.

Comment: I've published the code that rapresent the creation of the groups and then the rect